# amazon s3 iphone sdk downloading images

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to implement amazon's sdk in my iOS project, and I can't seem to find much documentation on what I am trying to do.

I want to, very simply, download files from my Amazon S3 account and store them locally on the iPhone. I can do it by accessing the images through the http address, but that doesn't protect the images like I would prefer.

From what I have read, I should be doing something like this:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"mykey" withSecretKey:@"mysecretkey"];
        
        S3GetObjectRequest *requestedObject = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:bucketPath withBucket:@"mybucket"];
 
        NSLog(@"requestedobject:%@", requestedObject - I get the log here);
        
        S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [s3Client getObject:requestedObject];
        
        NSLog(@"requestedobject2:%@", getObjectResponse - it crashes before this happens);
        NSData *myData2;
        myData2 = getObjectResponse.body;
        [myData2 writeToFile:bucketPath atomically:YES];
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong with the getObjectResponse, getObject code, but I can't figure out the correct syntax... any help would be appreciated it!

Here is the log:
2012-08-02 17:12:33.856 Collection Master Edition[13176:4e07] requestedobject:<S3GetObjectRequest: 0x96ac380>
2012-08-02 17:12:34.044 Collection Master Edition[13176:4e07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'AmazonServiceException', reason: '(null)'

Maybe I should also mention I CAN get the bucket list contents with the following code

```
 S3ListObjectsRequest *listObjectRequest = [[S3ListObjectsRequest alloc] initWithName:@"my bucket"];
        
        S3ListObjectsResponse *listObjectResponse = [s3Client listObjects:listObjectRequest];
        
        S3ListObjectsResult *listObjectsResults = listObjectResponse.listObjectsResult;
        
        for (S3ObjectSummary *objectSummary in listObjectsResults.objectSummaries) {
            NSLog(@"Bucket Contents:%@" ,[objectSummary key]); // This returns the contents of the bucket
        }
```

Comment: You might want to reconsider doing this and instead add a web service layer in between your iOS app and S3.  Otherwise you are going to need to place your AWS credentials into the app itself.  So if someone hacks your app, they have full access to your S3 storage (and any other Amazon services available to that key).

Comment: I've thought about that, and have set up the TVM web service layer... but I can't get past the first step to start testing the TVM step... I figure if I can get the above code working, I can move forward (and ask some more questions!) for getting a TVM working - thoughts? Unless you have suggestions for the whole thing!

Comment: Hey, have you solved this issue? I am facing the same problem here.

Comment: To any one who is experiencing the same issue, this post helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318487/aws-s3-sdk-for-ios-putobjectregquest-to-new-region-not-working

Answer (score 1):

From what I see here you may have one of two problems. I had similar issues when first starting to use AWS. First make sure you bucket name is in all lowercase letters. You should check to see why this is happening by puuting it in a @try - @catch block and logging the errors, which provide great detail when figuring out your problem.

```
    -(UIImage *)getImageFromS3{      


    @try{
    AmazonS3Client *_s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc]initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];      

    S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc]initWithKey:imageKey withBucket:pictureBucket];

  S3GetObjectResponse *response = [_s3Client getObject:getObjectRequest];

    if (response.error == nil)
    {
        if (response.body != nil)
        {
        UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageWithData:reponse.body];
    return someImage;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"There was no value in the response body");
            return nil;
             }
    }
    else if (response.error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"There was an error in the response while getting image: %@",response.error.description);
    }
}

    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"There was an exception when connecting to s3: %@",exception.description);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What could be the issue is the permissions associated with your key pair. What I advise is to go your [IAM on your Management Console](http://wwww.console.aws.amazoncom) and create a new group with the proper S3 permissions you want, in this case almost all of them except for some of the more administrative things you won't need (so mainly just POST, GET permissions). Then create a user within that group and use that key pair for testing. This may clear things up as that is the process I think worked for me. It seems that the list permission is fairly low level, however, POST and GET require different permissions.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is let, but might help some one. Here is the code to upload image in amazone-s3

```
constant.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#define SECRET_KEY             @"your secret kry"
#define ACCESS_KEY_ID          @"your access id"
```

#define PICTURE_BUCKET         @"bucket name"
   #define PICTURE_NAME           @"any word"
   #define CREDENTIALS_ERROR_TITLE    @"Missing Credentials"
   #define CREDENTIALS_ERROR_MESSAGE  @"AWS Credentials not configured correctly.  Please review the   README file."

@interface Constant : NSObject

+(NSString *)pictureBucket;

@end

In constant.m

#import "Constant.h"

@implementation Constant
   +(NSString *)pictureBucket
   {
    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", PICTURE_BUCKET, ACCESS_KEY_ID] lowercaseString];
    }

```
@end
```

In UploadViewController.h

```
  typedef enum {
  GrandCentralDispatch,
  Delegate,
  BackgroundThread
  } UploadType;

  @interface UploadPhotoViewController :  UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, AmazonServiceRequestDelegate>
 {
UploadType _uploadType;
 }

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonSelectPhoto;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) AmazonS3Client *s3;
```

In UploadViewController.m

```
      #import "UploadPhotoViewController.h"
       #import <AWSRuntime/AWSRuntime.h>
      #import "Constant.h"

       @interface UploadPhotoViewController ()

        @end

         @implementation UploadPhotoViewController

     - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
        {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
      }
       return self;
     }

       - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

     #ifdef DEBUG
     [AmazonLogger verboseLogging];
   #else
      [AmazonLogger turnLoggingOff];
   #endif

     [AmazonErrorHandler shouldNotThrowExceptions];

      if(![ACCESS_KEY_ID isEqualToString:@"CHANGE ME"]
          && self.s3 == nil)
       {
    // Initial the S3 Client.
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // This sample App is for demonstration purposes only.
    // It is not secure to embed your credentials into source code.
    // DO NOT EMBED YOUR CREDENTIALS IN PRODUCTION APPS.
    // We offer two solutions for getting credentials to your mobile App.
    // Please read the following article to learn about Token Vending Machine:
    // * http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Mobile/4611615499399490
    // Or consider using web identity federation:
    // * http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Mobile/4617974389850313
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY] ;
    self.s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_WEST_2];

    // Create the picture bucket.
    S3CreateBucketRequest *createBucketRequest = [[S3CreateBucketRequest alloc] initWithName:[Constant pictureBucket] andRegion:[S3Region USWest2]];
    S3CreateBucketResponse *createBucketResponse = [self.s3 createBucket:createBucketRequest];
    if(createBucketResponse.error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", createBucketResponse.error);
    }
}

  }
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if ([ACCESS_KEY_ID isEqualToString:@"CHANGE ME"])
{
    [self showAlertMessage:CREDENTIALS_ERROR_MESSAGE withTitle:CREDENTIALS_ERROR_TITLE];
}
```

}
- (void)showAlertMessage:(NSString *)message withTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alertView.delegate=self;
    [alertView show];
     }
          - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    // Set the content type so that the browser will treat the URL as an image.
    S3ResponseHeaderOverrides *override = [[S3ResponseHeaderOverrides alloc] init];
    override.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

    // Request a pre-signed URL to picture that has been uplaoded.
    S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
    gpsur.key                     = PICTURE_NAME;
    gpsur.bucket                  = [Constant pictureBucket];
    gpsur.expires                 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval) 3600]; // Added an hour's worth of seconds to the current time.
    gpsur.responseHeaderOverrides = override;

    // Get the URL
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [self.s3 getPreSignedURL:gpsur error:&error];

    if(url == nil)
    {
        if(error != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self showAlertMessage:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Browser Error"];
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /*dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Display the URL in Safari
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

        });*/
    }NSLog(@"url is %@",url);

});

 }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

   - (IBAction)buttonTakePhoto:(id)sender
   {
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.delegate = self;

picker.allowsEditing = YES;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;



[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }

   - (IBAction)buttonSelectPhoto:(id)sender
   {
 [self showImagePicker:Delegate];
 }

    - (void)showImagePicker:(UploadType)uploadType
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] ;
imagePicker.delegate = self;

_uploadType = uploadType;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
   }


  - (void)processDelegateUpload:(NSData *)imageData
 {
// Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:PICTURE_NAME
                                                          inBucket:[Constant pictureBucket]];
por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
por.data = imageData;
por.delegate = self;

// Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
[self.s3 putObject:por];
 }

     -(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
  {
[self showAlertMessage:@"The image was successfully uploaded." withTitle:@"Upload Completed"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
  }

 -(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
  {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
[self showAlertMessage:error.description withTitle:@"Upload Error"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
  }

   #pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods

       -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
// Get the selected image.
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// Convert the image to JPEG data.
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);


if(_uploadType == Delegate)
{
    [self processDelegateUpload:imageData];
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   }

   -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
  {
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   }

     - (IBAction)buttonBack:(id)sender
     {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }

   @end
```