# aws s3 sdk for iOS putObjectRegquest to "new" region not working

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

first let me say that I am new ios/xcode as well as AWS.

I am creating an app that writes data to an AWS S3 bucket. The app works when creating a bucket and putting objects to the US Standard Region. However, when I change the region to Singapore, the app creates the bucket successfully - but, I cannot put objects into the bucket and AWS does not produce an error or exception of any kind.

Here is the code in question. The commented code in the createBucket method successfully creates a bucket in Singapore. The processGrandCentralDispatchUpload method is works for the US Standard region, but does not put objects to my Singapore bucket.

```
- (void)createBucket
{
// Create the bucket.
@try {

    //S3Region *region = [[S3Region alloc] initWithStringValue:kS3RegionAPSoutheast1];
    //S3CreateBucketRequest *createBucketRequest = [[S3CreateBucketRequest alloc] initWithName:[Constants S3Bucket] andRegion:region];

    S3CreateBucketRequest *createBucketRequest = [[S3CreateBucketRequest alloc] initWithName:[Constants S3Bucket]];
    S3CreateBucketResponse *createBucketResponse = [self.s3 createBucket:createBucketRequest];

    NSLog(@"create bucket response: %@", createBucketResponse.error);

    if(createBucketResponse.error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", createBucketResponse.error);
    }
}

@catch (AmazonServiceException* asex) {
    NSLog(@"putObject - AmazonServiceException - %@", asex);
}

@catch (AmazonClientException* acex) {
    NSLog(@"putObject - AmazonClientException - %@", acex);
}
```

}

```
- (void)processGrandCentralDispatchUpload:(NSData *)jsonData withTimestamp:(int)timestamp
```

{

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    UserData * user = [[[DataStore defaultStore] user] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString * dateKeyComponent = [self putRequestDateComponent:timestamp];

    objectName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", user.email, user.uniqueIdentifier, dateKeyComponent];

    S3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:objectName
                                                             inBucket:[Constants S3Bucket]];
    putObjectRequest.contentType = @"data/json";
    putObjectRequest.data = jsonData;

    // Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.

    @try {
        S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:putObjectRequest];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(putObjectResponse.error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", putObjectResponse.error);
                [self showAlertMessage:[putObjectResponse.error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Upload Error"];
            }
            else
            {
                //[self showAlertMessage:@"The data was successfully uploaded." withTitle:@"Upload Completed"];
            }

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
        });
    }

    @catch (AmazonServiceException* asex) {
        NSLog(@"putObject - AmazonServiceException - %@", asex);
    }

    @catch (AmazonClientException* acex) {
        NSLog(@"putObject - AmazonClientException - %@", acex);
    }

});
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  I'm sorry you're encountering difficulties.

If your bucket name contains non alpha numeric characters you may need to set the endpoint of the Amazon S3 client to the region of your bucket.

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentialsProvider:provider];
s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:AP_SOUTHEAST_1];
```

You can also turn on verbose logging in your application to see the raw responses from the service while using the SDK.  If you do see errors coming back that are not being captured, please let us know.

```
[AmazonLogger verboseLogging];
```

A couple things I will note about your code that you may also want to consider:

- Once the bucket is created, you no longer need to call create bucket.  You may want to consider removing the `S3CreateBucketRequest/S3CreateBucketResponse` from your application.
- S3 bucket naming is unique across all regions.  If the bucket was created in US Standard then you cannot create it in Singapore without first deleting the bucket in US Standard.
- You seem to be mixing both exception and error handling in your code.  Please see [our blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2PZV371MJJHUG/How-Not-to-Throw-Exceptions-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS) on how to control exception handling in the SDK.

Comment: I was on 1.7.0 and recently just realized (after adding error logging in my app) that my `S3.putObject` would occasionally fail and throw an exception. I just upgraded to 1.7.1 and added `endpoint` per your suggestion and hope that would fix it. (Yes, my bucket name does contain dashes)

Comment: Nope, 1.7.1 does not fix it. I still get exceptions and it can't be caught with try/catch, probably because it's running on a different thread. At this point, I am just going to hold off on using this SDK until there is a definite fix :(